# What permissions to I need to run a OWIN self-hosted app as non-admin user?

Tags: c#, .net, owin

What permission is required, to allow a user to start an OWIN self-hosted webservice that listens to non-localhost IPs?

I'm trying to run a self-hosted webservice in a commandline app/windows service.

I've been trying many things.

With the app running on machine mydomainname, and IP address 192.168.0.153:

1. I build the app so that WebApp.Start() initializes with the url "http://localhost:9980/":

   - I can run the app as an ordinary user.
   - If a client on the same machine makes calls against "http://localhost:9980/...", everything works.
   - If a client on the same machine makes calls against "http://127.0.0.1:9980/...", I get HTTP 400 - Invalid Hostname.
   - Clients not on the same machine cannot access the webservice, as is only to be expected.
2. I build the app so that WebApp.Start() initializes with the url "http://+:9980/":

   - If I run the app as an ordinary user I get an "Access is denied" exception.
   - If I run the app as an admin user, things work.
   - If a client on the same machine makes calls against "http://localhost:9980/...", everything works.
   - If a client on the same machine makes calls against "http://127.0.0.1:9980/...", everything works.
   - If a client on the same machine makes calls against "http://mydomainname:9980/...", everything works.
   - If I have not enabled an inbound rule on port 9980, clients not on the same machine get timeouts, of course.
   - If I have enabled an inbound rule on port 9980, clients not on the same machine work just fine, using mydomainname or IP address 192.168.0.153.

But here's the thing - I cannot hand this over to ops with the requirement that it run as admin.

3. So I tried building the app so that WebApp.Start() initializes with multiple urls: "http://localhost:9980/", "http://127.0.0.1:9980/", "http://mydomainname:9980/". (Note - not including 192.168.0.153).

   - When I run as non-admin I get that "Access is denied" exception, again.
   - When I run as admin, it works.
   - Local clients using localhost. 127.0.0.1, and mydomainname work, local clients using machine's IP address do not.
   - Remote clients using mydomainname work, remote clients using 192.168.0.153 do not.
4. So I tried building the app so that WebApp.Start() initializes with multiple localhost urls: "http://localhost:9980/", "http://127.0.0.1:9980/".

   - When I run as non-admin things work fine.
5. So I tried building the app so that WebApp.Start() initializes with "http://192.1680.153:9980/". (The IP address of the server machine).

   - When I run as non-admin I get that "Access is denied" exception, again.

I've been browsing around trying to find advice, for all of this, and I've seen posts that say I need to use netsh to configure a urlacl, and posts that say that I can't have any urlacls configured, and nothing I've seen from anyone suggests that anyone has any definitive answers for how this works, or is supposed to work.

It seems clear to me that there is some specific permission that a user must have in order to start OWIN so that it listens to a non-localhost IP. And that admin has it and my normal login does not.

Does anyone have any idea what this permission might be, and how to grant it to a normal login user?

I can't deliver an app that needs admin rights to run.

I can, though, deliver an app that when run by a user that doesn't have some specific right configured, exits with a "HEY! You need to grant the user permission XXX".

But what permission is required, to allow a user to start an OWIN self-hosted webservice that listens to non-localhost IPs?

Comment: run `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9980/ user=EVERYONE` just once with admin rights. *Access is denied* will vanish

Comment: Unfortunately, limiting malware from opening random ports is a necessary evil.  That's why this restriction exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L.B's comment included the correct answer - I need to grant the user permission to open that specific port.

I've modified the app to recognize that specific error. When it catches a `TargetInvocationException` with an `InnerException` that is a `HttpListenerException`, and that has an `ErrorCode == 5`, I display an error message that tells the user precisely what needs to be done:

> Starting WebApp on port: 9980
>
> ERROR User does not have permission to start webservice on port 9980.
>
> To grant a user permission to start a webservice on this machine, run in an administrative console (once):
>
> > netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9980/ user=<username>
>
> or:
>
> > netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9980/ user=EVERYONE